# Issue while ng new app-name angular cli 6.0.4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed angular cli `6.0.4` using `npm install -g @angular/cli` and when I try to create a new project using this command `ng new my-first-app` It's throwing the following error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"dryRun":false,"version":"6.0.4","skipGit":false,"skipInstall":false,"linkCli":false,"commit":true,"newProjectRoot":"projects","inlineStyle":false,"inlineTemplate":false,"routing":false,"prefix":"app","style":"css","skipTests":false}
Errors:

Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun).
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Looks like the new 6.0.5 version fixed this issue
```

[more info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11006)

Comment: Unfortunately, due to some issue found after doing the 6.0.4 release, we were forced to rollback. This release is the same as 6.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Here, refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544714/webstorm-new-angularcli-project-error-directory-should-match-format-path) and [this](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular-eclipse/issues/116). Similar error.

Try these possible options:

1. Uninstall current angular/cli and try downloading some older version.
2. Update node version and delete npm cache.
3. Better still, if your sole aim is angular 6 then a workaround could be to [download](https://angular.io/tutorial) example and get rid of unwanted files and install all the packages you need.