# After angular 7.0 update

Tags: angular, angular7

I updated to angular 7 and im getting this error when trying to create a new angular project.

ng new error:

[image]

angular version:

[image]

Comment: Did you update from 6 to 7?

Comment: can you run this both command npm ls -g @schematics/angular
and npm ls @schematics/angular  and tell what error is coming ?

Comment: @HrishikeshKale when i ran the command locally i got this error : npm ERR! extraneous: @schematics/angular@7.0.3 /home/alangeorge/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@schematics/angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved:

there was a folder named "node_modules" in my home directory.
deleting it solved the case.

for more refer:
[ng new has stopped working after updating to Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198408/ng-new-has-stopped-working-after-updating-to-angular-6)

Comment: I hope you actually understood the problem. The "node_modules" is the folder that's installed when you install npm. Most probably when you installed version 6 and then updated to version 7, the folder did not update and hence the error. So deleting it caused to create a new one. Also you can mark your answer as correct since it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You try with `--version` option 
For example

`ng new test-app --version 7`

This solution is definitely working for you

Answer (score 0):

"New project names must start with a letter, and must contain only alphanumeric characters or dashes. When adding a dash the segment after the dash must also start with a letter.

Invalid- new_something

Valid- new-something"

I'd advise you change your naming convention

try: angular-project

[WebStorm: New AngularCli Project: Error: directory should match format "path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544714/webstorm-new-angularcli-project-error-directory-should-match-format-path)

Comment: then most likely a failed install try
npm uninstall @angular/cli -g
npm install @angular/cli -g

also try reading this answer hopefully it provides a solution for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198408/ng-new-has-stopped-working-after-updating-to-angular-6